# Add actual HTML elements to PRE/CODE contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a quick/dirty way to add some syntax highlighting for pre/code tags in html using javascript.

The problem i'm running into, is that if i edit either the text() or html(), I get escaped content. That is, the added tags render as pre/code, or i get a bunch of eascape characters.

Consider the following html:

```
<pre>
    <code class="target">
    public interface __iIFoo { }
    public class __tBar : __iIFoo { }

    var list = new List__/__iIFoo\__();
    </code>
</pre>
```

The goal here is to replace occurrences of `__iIFoo` with:

```
<span class="interface">IFoo</span>
```

So that it can be highlighted with css. And of course, when it's rendered, I don't want to see the actual SPAN tag.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(function(){
    var iPatt = /__i\w+/g
    $.each($(".target").text().match(iPatt), function(i,match){
        var replace = '<span class="interface">'+match.substring(3)+'</span>';
        $(".target").text(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace(match, replace);
        });
    });
});
```

This works, BUT, the span tags I'm adding show up in the rendered content e.g. they are just like all the other pre code. I don't want to see it!

Comment: Change the html rather than the text.

Comment: if use `html()` instead of `text()`, then I end up with escaped characters like &lt;span class="interface"&gt; that shows up in the rendered content. I want actual DOM elments added inside the pre element.

Comment: No, `text()` escapes it... you've got it backwards.

Comment: ah, you guys mean the `$(".target").text()`. yes that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`. When you use `.text()`, the value is the literal text that you want users to see, so it replaces special HTML characters with entities so they'll show up literally.

Comment: all the answers were essentially the same, however you were the first. just being fair!

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wUK3m/1)

`.text()` treats value as text and `.html()` render it as html content

```
$(".target").html(function () { //replace text with html
    return $(this).text().replace(match, replace);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using it with `html` instead:

```
$(function(){
    var iPatt = /__i\w+/g
    $.each($(".target").text().match(iPatt), function(i,match){
        var replace = '<span class="interface">'+match.substring(3)+'</span>';
        $(".target").html(function(){
            return $(this).text().replace(match, replace);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, change the html rather than the text ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/pKwPP/)).

As a side-note, it's worrisome that you're completely overwriting the contents of `.target` every time you encounter a match. You should take advantage of [RegExp capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches) and perform only one assignment.

```
(function () {
    var iPattern = /__i(\w+)/g,
        iTemplate = "<span class='interface'>$1</span>";

    $(".target").each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(iPattern, iTemplate);
    });
})();
```